# How to configure CruiseControl.NET to build one project on a remote server

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, build-server

I have a build server running CruiseControl.NET. It works well for the 7 projects that are configured to run on that server (let's call it server A).

Now I have a new project that I wish to build on a different server (server B), but I want it to appear in the same ccnet dashboard as the existing projects.

How do I configure CCNet for this scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `dashboard.config` (default location is `c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\dashboard.config`) take a look at the [Servers Configuration Block](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Servers+Configuration+Block):

```
   <servers>
       <server name="local" url="tcp://localhost:21234/CruiseManager.rem"
               allowForceBuild="true" allowStartStopBuild="true" />
   </servers>
```

It allows you to configure the remote servers you want to report on - just add another `<server />` node.
To force the changes to appear on your CruiseControl.NET dashboard, edit the web.config file in the same folder and save it. Refresh the dashboard web page.

Answer (score 2):

Duckworth's answer is the one I found via Google. I found the complete story (identifying all protagonists) as:

Open the dashboard.config file. Its default location is \Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard.

At the top of dashboard.config, add the extra server. Eg

and save the changes.

To force the changes to appear on your CruiseControl.NET dashboard, edit the web.config file in the same folder and save it. Refresh the dashboard web page.

Comment: Do you think this would work across platforms?  I want to have a Unix CruiseControl instance monitor a Windows CruiseControl.NET instance, and in fact control it (i.e. kick off builds).

Comment: It does work cross platform. However, CC.Net is far from perfect on *nix - save yourself a lot of headaches and run the Dashboard on Windows.